# Spring framework upgrade - Modifying the code

Tags: spring, frameworks, upgrade

Trying to upgrade a springframe work project from very old version to latest version 5.3. After replacing old jar files with new I am seeing compile errors. Below is the sample code. Appreciate your help to update the below code using the latest framework.

Errors @ 1. SimpleFormContrller - Not found
2. retun new RedirectView(getSuccessView() - Notfound.

```
public class RangeFormController extends SimpleFormController {

   Protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
  }
}

 Spring-Context.xml
<bean id="RangeFormController " 
 class="org.test.controller.RangeFormController ">
  <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
  <property name="commandName"><value>fileUpload</value></property>      
  <property name="formView"><value>FileUpload</value></property>
  <property name="successView"><value>upload.html</value></property>      
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleFormController` was deprecated in 3.0. You should use `@Controller` instead as follows:

```java
@Controller
public class RangeFormController {

}
```

As a consequence `getSuccessView()` will also not be available. Simply use a String as a parameter to `RedirectView`. Reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html#RedirectView-java.lang.String-.

Comment: Updated my post with springcontext.xml. Do I need to add @Mapping "RangeFormController " as well ? and what should i replace for getSuccessView() based on the spring-context file ?

Comment: Please don't use XML in Spring 5.3. Annotations and JavaConfig replaced XML long ago.